# Connecting client to the mediasoup server via webrtc

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, mediasoup

I have a video conferencing application which contains two servers 1) Main server which contains the business logic. 2) Media server (mediasoup). Basically clients connects to the main server via websockets. When they make a request for joining a room the request is first sent to the main server via websockets which checks if the user is allowed to join and after checking the permissions the main server send a message via rabbitmq to fetch the room info from the mediaserver. Now my main question is after doing all this how do i make a connection between client and mediaserver if the user has joined the room. I want to make a connection between client and mediserver via webrtc but i am unable to figure out how to do it. Its basically for my own project and i have searched a lot but i am unable to come up with a solution. Much appreciated